# Sed expression not working in cron job

Tags: linux, bash, sed, cron

I have a sh file with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Scripts para limpiar los JS"
find . -type f  -name "*.js" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "s/var _0xaae8=.*//"
echo "Finalizo la limpieza de JS"
```

If I run this line isolated in the server, it works perfectly:

```
find . -type f  -name "*.js" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "s/var _0xaae8=.*//"
```

But when I run the script in the cron-job I get this error message:

```
Scripts para limpiar los JS
sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unknown option to `s'
sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unknown option to `s'
sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unknown option to `s'
sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unknown option to `s'
find: `./.checkers': Permission denied
sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unknown option to `s'
Finalizo la limpieza de JS
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could we see your crontab?

Comment: Yes, of course:

    45 11 * * * bash /home/cmspeopl/public_html/scripts-limpieza.sh

Comment: Maybe try `find . -type f  -name "*.js" -maxdepth 1 -exec sed -i 's/var _0xaae8=.*//g' {} \;` and see if there's any difference.

Comment: Response from server:

find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: Don't forget, `cron` runs as `root` and even if it's your own `cron` it runs in a very limited environment and in a different LOCATION.  If you look at your first error you get a "Permission Denied".  I'm assuming the dot in your `find` is looking in a directory it is not supposed to be and therefore `sed` has no valid input.  Do not put `.` in your `find` input.